# sed remove with regex

Tags: regex, sed

I have code that contains

```
#ifdef CEEDLING_TESTS
void scheduler_task_delay_update(uint8_t task_index) {
#else
static void scheduler_task_delay_update(uint8_t task_index) {
#endif
```

I want to remove everything except

```
void scheduler_task_delay_update(uint8_t task_index) {
```

So I created a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $PWD
for f in $(find src/ -type f)
do
    sed -i '/#ifdef CEEDLING_TESTS/d' $f
    sed -i '/#else/d' $f
    sed -i '/#endif/d' $f
    sed -i '/^static/d' $f
done
```

This works 99% of the time. Except when I have code that starts as

```
static void run_task(uint8_t task_index) {
```

This code is not wrapped with `ifdef`. How can I differentiate between the two using sed and regex?

Edit: Using an online regex parser this should find the text in question:

```
sed -i '/#ifdef CEEDLING_TESTS/d' $f
sed -i -E "s/#else.*static/temp/g" $f
```

Edit 2: Found an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242469/how-to-use-sed-grep-to-extract-text-between-two-words), tried to recreate:

```
sed -i -e 's/.*#else\(.*\)#endif.*/\1/' $f
```

Comment: Side note: [Bash pitfall number 1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: Very interesting! I found this answer on another stack exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this with the following!

```
for f in src/**/*.c
do
    sed -i '/#ifdef CEEDLING_TESTS/d' $f
    sed -i '/#else/,/#endif/d' $f
done
```